# Div unknown height smooth transition

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div which changing it's content on AJAX call (quote machine). There's no any CSS `height` specified on the div and it's parents. I applied the following CSS for the div:

```
height: auto
-moz-transition: all 3s linear
-webkit-transition: all 3s linear
transition: all 3s linear
```

But this is uneffective. Here is a JSfiddle for visual presentation: https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/mfbeLa2d/22/

**Edit:**

I included the Fiddle here:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#getMessage").on("click", function () {
    $("#changeThis").html("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #777;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  
  height: auto
  -moz-transition: all 3s linear
  -webkit-transition: all 3s linear
  transition: all 3s linear
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="child" id="changeThis">
    This div's height will change on button click.
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="button" id="getMessage">Button</button>
</div><!-- .content -->
```

Comment: What is your desired outcome? You dont want the height of the div to change?

Comment: The desired outcome is to apply CSS `transition` to this div, this way I want to smoothly change it's height when the AJAX call populating with new content. Included JSfiddle giving visual presentation where it should have the smooth height transition.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `animate` function

HTML and CSS can remain the same but your JS should be updated as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#getMessage").on("click", function () {
    $("#changeThis").animate({height:$(window).height()},500).html("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.");
  });
});
```

I added animate function and you may adjust the speed (set at 500 here), read more about the animate function here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/  Note that the animation takes place before the text is added.

Also added is the height to be set to `$(window).height()` so that the box expands to the full height fo the viewport.

### [Updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4k5cr4y1/)

Comment: Is it possible to only grow for the div's height? This block is for a quote machine where the block is placed in the center of the screen. Overflow to the entire screen height is not an option. Sorry for the long text example, usually the div never overflowing the screen height, just in the JSfiddle.

Comment: @Lanti you can make the height whatever you want the height to be, just replace `$(window).height()` with something else, if you want it to be 200px tall then change it to `200` See more here http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: What if on the next click you query another quote with different text length and your divs height will be more than 200px, let's say 536px? On the third click, you refresh the api and you got a new text and your div's height will be 135px. That's why hardcoding the height in pixels is not possible, because (as in the question), the div's height always will be unknown.

Comment: So get height of the div based on the div's class or id, for example if the div has a class `divclass` then get the height of that class like so `$(".divclass").height()`

Comment: I already tried this once, not working because I think when the clicking on the button happens JS doesn't know the new height, because I think the new content not yet in the DOM: https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/4k5cr4y1/4/